# Chocolatey returns errors when installing openvpn

Tags: powershell, windows-10, package-managers, openvpn, chocolatey

As the title describes, `choco install openvpn` returns the below error;

```
ERROR: Unable to import PGP key 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\openvpn\tools\openvpn_public_key.asc' in the temporary keyring (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\openvpn\tools\e090a0df-7709-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\pubring.gpg).
The install of openvpn was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\openvpn\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.


Failures
 - openvpn (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\openvpn\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

I am using a `Windows 10, v1803` machine.

Below is the part of the log that shows the complete traced error;

```
[DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\openvpn.2.4.7\.arguments".
[DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\openvpn.2.4.7\.extra".
[DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\openvpn.2.4.7\.version".
[DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\openvpn.2.4.7\.sxs".
[DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\openvpn.2.4.7\.pin".
[DEBUG] - Attempting to delete directory "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib-bad\openvpn".
[DEBUG] - Sending message 'HandlePackageResultCompletedMessage' out if there are subscribers...
[ERROR] - The install of openvpn was NOT successful.
[ERROR] - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\openvpn\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
[DEBUG] - Moving 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\openvpn'
 to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib-bad\openvpn'
[DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache\openvpn.2.4.7.nupkg".
[WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
[INFO ] - 
[ERROR] - Failures
[ERROR] -  - openvpn (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\openvpn\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
[DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
[DEBUG] - Exiting with -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution which is disabling the `git` PATH used where as it puts the version of `gpg.exe` shipped with git ahead of the one from `openvpn` package on my environment variables.

This could be done in two ways;

The first is editing the environment PATH variables and moving `git` PATH below the `C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub` PATH, see the picture below.
[image]

The second is removing/deleting the `git` PATH variables then start a new `powershell` session, run `choco install openvpn` then returning the `git` PATH back to the env variables.

In my case, the fist option worked just fine.